# Called javaScript function from jquery dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call javascript function from jquery dialog buton, but it is not working

my code :

```
============================
$('#dialogAddActe').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 800,
        height:400,
        show: "slide",
        hide: "slide",
        buttons: {
            "Suivant": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 

                if ($(this).checkNombre())
                {

                document.forms[0].dispatch.value = "ajouterActe";
                document.forms[0].submit();

                }

            }, 
            "Annuler": function() { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                document.forms[0].patientId.value="";
            } 
        }
    });

============================
```

`$(this).checkNombre()`  is not working.

BR,
Med Baba

Comment: Here `this` refers to the `dialog` element in question.

Comment: I tried if (checkNombre()) but it is not working

Comment: OK, "not working" is not very useful. You need to tell us what error you are receiving, or what is happening. Also we need the code for the `checkNombre()` function.

Comment: Is `checkNombre()` a jQuery method? Where is it defined?

Comment: Now is working I had some javascript error, variable name was wrong.
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$(this)`, just use `if (checkNombre())`.